# Generating exponential function Lah numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In Analytic Combinatorics by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick it is mentioned that the generating function of Lah numbers (called fragmented permutations) is
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}L(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^{x/(1-x)}
\end{equation}

but in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159377/generating-function-of-lah-numbers)they arrive at another result using even another notation ($L (n, k)$).

I understand that $L(n)\neq L(n,k)$ since they have different recurrence relationships. my question is, knowing that the recurrence relationship of $L(n)$ is

\begin{equation}
L(n+1)=(2n+1)L(n)-(n^2-n)L(n-1); n\geq 1
\end{equation}

How to can prove

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}L(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^{x/(1-x)}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

We can certainly prove the recurrence from the EGF. With $L_n = n!
[z^n] \exp(z/(1-z))$ which BTW is the combinatorial class
(compare to Stirling numbers)

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\textsc{SEQ}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

we obtain by differentiating

$$L(z) = \exp(z/(1-z))$$

that

$$n! [z^n] L'(z) = L_{n+1}
= n! [z^n] L(z) \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}
\\ = n! \sum_{q=0}^n
[z^q] L(z) [z^{n-q}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}
= n! \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!} L_q (n-q+1)
\\ = (n+1)! \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!} L_q
- n! \sum_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{(q-1)!} L_q.$$

This also yields

$$(n+1) L_{n+1} = - (n+1)! \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!} L_q
+ (n+2)! \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!} L_q
- (n+1)! \sum_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{(q-1)!} L_q.$$

Subtract from

$$L_{n+2} = (n+2)! \sum_{q=0}^{n+1} \frac{1}{q!} L_q
- (n+1)! \sum_{q=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{(q-1)!} L_q$$

to get

$$L_{n+2} = (n+1) L_{n+1}
+ (n+1)! \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!} L_q
+ (n+2) L_{n+1} - (n+1) L_{n+1}
\\ = (n+2) L_{n+1} + (n+1)! \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!} L_q.$$

This yields

$$(n+2) L_{n+2} = (n+2)^2 L_{n+1}
+ (n+2)! \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!} L_q$$

as well as

$$L_{n+3} = (n+3) L_{n+2}
+ (n+2)! \sum_{q=0}^{n+1} \frac{1}{q!} L_q.$$

Subtract one more time to get

$$L_{n+3} = (2n+5) L_{n+2} - (n+2)^2 L_{n+1}
+ (n+2) L_{n+1}
\\ = (2n+5) L_{n+2} - (n+2)(n+1) L_{n+1}$$

Setting $n$ to $n-2$ we get

$$L_{n+1} = (2n+1) L_n - n(n-1) L_{n-1}$$

as claimed.